# assembly: stuck - reading in text file

Tags: file, assembly, file-io, x86, nasm

Below is what I hope is the relevant code from my NASM program.  Once int 080h is called, the debugger is showing -9 for eax.  The text in my test.txt is 321314145.  I've been staring at this for hours and I've hit a dead end here.  Why is this happening?

```
%define BUFLEN 128
%define READLEN 3
%define SYSCALL_READ  3

    SECTION .bss                    ; uninitialized data section
buf:    resb READLEN                     ; buffer for read
rlen:   resb 4
newstr: resb BUFLEN

; read file name from arg

    ;
    pop     ebx         ;not using

    pop     ebx         ;not using

    pop     ebx         ;pop filename

; open file
;
    mov     eax, SYSCALL_OPEN
    mov     ecx, STDIN
    int     080h

    mov     eax, SYSCALL_READ ; read function
    mov     ebx, eax      ; Arg: file descriptor
    mov     ecx, buf      ; Arg: address of buffer
    mov     edx, READLEN      ; Arg: buffer length
    int     080h
```

Comment: How come you seem to be opening `stdin` and yet your text is in a file?

Comment: i was just using the constant, its pointing to 0, which is readonly mode

Comment: Use `strace ./a.out` to trace your system calls and see that you're passing garbage as args for `open(2)`, so of course you get a -ERRNO return value instead of a fd.

Answer (score 0):

```
mov     eax, SYSCALL_READ ; read function
mov     ebx, eax      ; Arg: file descriptor
```

You're kidding, right?

the `-9` is "bad file number" (per errno.h). Make sure that your sys_open succeeds, then put `eax` in `ebx`.... BEFORE altering `eax`!

Comment: test eax, eax  is apparently raising a flag.  jns isnt jumping